# Link pointing to illegal content

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, inappropriate-content

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12189302/825789) contained a link to a warez site run or developed by the OP. Not only the link pointed to illegal content, but also didn't add much value to the question, so I edited it out. Was this the right thing to do? Should any further action be taken?

Comment: According to [TOS](http://stackexchange.com/legal), part 3 Subscriber Content `"Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that [...] c) infringes any intellectual property right of another or the privacy or publicity rights of another"`, it is the right thing to do to save the question.

Comment: @nhahtdh You should post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: I didn't because I didn't know the answer to the 2nd question (`Should any further action be taken?`)

Comment: @nhahtdh The TOS would be a sufficient answer (imho), don't post answers as comments or someone might steal them ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) (emphasis mine):

> #### 3. Subscriber Content
>
> Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that (a) infringes, violates or otherwise interferes with any copyright or trademark of another party, (b) reveals any trade secret, unless Subscriber owns the trade secret or has the owner’s permission to post it, (**c) infringes any intellectual property right of another or the privacy or publicity rights of another**, (d) is libelous, defamatory, abusive, threatening, harassing, hateful, offensive or otherwise violates any law or right of any third party, (e) contains a virus, trojan horse, worm, time bomb or other computer programming routine or engine that is intended to damage, detrimentally interfere with, surreptitiously intercept or expropriate any system, data or information, or (f) remains posted after Subscriber has been notified that such Subscriber Content violates any of sections (a) to (e) of this sentence.

Editing the question and removing the link was appropriate. I also checked the user's other questions quickly, just in case he had a habit of posting the link. He doesn't, but had I found anything else I'd flag one of his posts for moderation attention to let team diamond know there's something fishy going on.

The user visited the question after your edit, so he probably noticed your edit message and since he didn't rollback I'm guessing he understood that sharing the link wasn't such a smart idea (and it was  pointless anyway).

Comment: I'm no lawyer, but I think the user was not directly violating the terms. The posted content itself was not illegal, but could lead to illegal content. Anyway, I take it that such links are not welcome on SE, right?

Comment: @bfavaretto well, since it didn't add much value to the post, and especially given that the link pointed to a site run by the poster, it probably qualifies as spam, and that itself makes it unwelcome. On the other hand, if a link to a site involved in shady activity _does_ add significant value to the post, then you'll get varying opinions, but I'd say it'd be fine. (Of course I can't think of an instance offhand where this actually happened...)