# Agentless centralized server management: where can I ask an open-ended question about this?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, list-questions

Where can I ask about the benefits and drawbacks of having an agentless configuration management or cloud management platform tool?  I don't see agents as *that* bad.  But some people think agents on servers are very undesirable.

Comment: [Probably nowhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145499/how-to-ask-best-practice-questions).

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that there is any Stack Exchange site suitable for that question in its current form because it is asking for a list of benefits and a list of drawbacks.

Focussed Q&A works best when you can imagine a single answer to your question, and it receives a few different descriptions of what that single answer may be, so that they can be voted upon to have the one generally thought best float to the top.

What you can do instead is to research and find what you think is the biggest single benefit or drawback and ask specifically about that i.e. "is it really a benefit/drawback when I think the opposite because ..."

Anyone seeing that who thinks you may be overlooking something bigger is likely to answer along the lines of "... I actually think there is a bigger benefit/drawback that you may be overlooking which is ... because ...".